# Get text from site using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the question number text from kahoot site (https://kahoot.it/challenge/15a3e9c2-65fe-4cb2-9441-a4023ed0e69e_1590141953862)

This is my code:

```
url='https://kahoot.it/challenge/15a3e9c2-65fe-4cb2-9441-a4023ed0e69e_1590141953862'
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
page_content = soup.find(class_='kahoot-title__Host-sc-1t7km5t-8 dVORBp')
artist_name_list_items = page_content.find_all('span')
print(artist_name_list_items)
```

When I run this I get this error message: `AttributeError:` `'NoneType'` object has no attribute `'find_all'`

Comment: so it means your selector `find(class_='kahoot-title__Host-sc-1t7km5t-8 dVORBp')` is not working - thats why `page_content` is `None` in next line where you're doing a `findall`

Comment: Your `soup.find()` is returning None because it's not matching anything

Comment: There is really no HTML content on that link, it's mostly just a blob of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because BeautifulSoup can't find an html element with the class 'kahoot-title__Host-sc-1t7km5t-8 dVORBp', and neither can I, unless I load JS within the browser.

Bs4 is usually used on static websites, and kahoot mostly uses javascript to serve content. You may be better off using a controlled browser like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: You can start by clicking on the link posted by @9 Guy

Comment: @bastostam1 ill edit with a selenium example if you'd like

Comment: i already got it working with selenium (i'm almost sure) thanks @9Guy